# Why does this return only one result?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have the following query. The query should be returning all five rows that I have where `user_id = 1`, but it's only returning the first result. Why?

```
$servers = DB::table('posts as p')
    ->select('p.id', 'p.content', DB::raw('COUNT(i.id) as num_results'))
    ->leftJoin('images as i', 'i.post_id', '=', 'p.id')
    ->where('p.user_id', Auth::id())
    ->get();
```

Thank you.

Comment: return DB::getQueryLog(); and check what is the output of this query you're running.

Comment: Could u provide us with the DB structure and what results u need to get?!!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index(User $user)
{

$users = $user
   ->where('rol','2')//for normal user 
   ->leftjoin('cityes', 'cityes.id', '=', 'users.cityes_id')
   ->select('users.id', 'users.name','cityes.name as city')
   ->get();
}
```

this code is work for me try this way